# Is database, user creation replicated on MySql?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I am deploying new application, I 'm using mysql 5.6

I setup database replication (master/slave).

I have a question:
Are tasks like database creation, User creation replicated to slave?
Do I have to create the database on each slave, or the replication will create them? do i have to create the user on each server or the operation will be replicated automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** and **No**

the reason how do you config the replication. there are many things in the configuration like ignore DB, ignore table and so on.

If nothing set all schemas, tables, views and so on are created and modifyed by
the Master.

So you CANT create a Schema,table or User on the SLAVE and later you create them on the Master. then the replication will stops with error.

Comment: So, if I setup replication on a fresh install, it will replicate new schemas and users, correct?
Any documentations or references please?

Comment: before you can start the replication you must dump the Master DB and import them into to slave. after this you can setup the slave from which server, user and password ... they get his infos and at which position it start. see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/setting-up-replication/

Comment: Thanks, I just need answer on a small bit: Is my current setup correct? will it replicate schema creation and user creation?

Comment: with your configuration you have a **full** copy of the maser db and if the master crashes you can config the slave to master (HA). if the speed of the replication is ok so its no reason to exclude some tables from replication.

Answer (score 1):

Replication should not include permission. Applications using master and slave should use different credentials and privileges to be always secure.

For eg, if I have a click-stream application, in master I will use clicker user with writes while slave will be used by a reporting tool with read-only with user name like clicker-ro or analyticsro. When I mean secure, a member of analytics should never have access to master db( to avoid writes and to avoid heavy queries in master)

Comment: You can set the permission via GRANT. so you can prevent access to the Master DB, but you can create the USER on Master.

This is the **ONLY** way to have a completed copy from the MASTER and you can change the SLAVE to MASTER if the MASTER crashed. If you not have all user in the SLAVE id dosent work

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the security implication, and know that this is not a best practice. I just need answer on a small bit: Is my current setup correct? will it replicate schema creation and user creation?